# Console app input and output

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

this is my simple C# console app in this i will get input from user i have postal code variable in which i want to take input as integer but when i input integer it shows error. another approch is that console.readline take both int and string as input or not ??

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string firstname;
        string lastname;
        string birthdate;
        string addressline1;
        string adressline2;
        string city;
        string stateorprovince;
        int    ziporpostalcode;
        string country;        
        ziporpostalcode =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());          
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: We can't help you fix an error if they only thing we know about the problem is that, "***it shows error***". What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you should Use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for `int.Parse`, Which is
>   responsible to Converts the string representation of a number to its
>   32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   operation succeeded, else return false(conversion failed)

So your code may looks like this:

```
int ziporpostalcode;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ziporpostalcode))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for entering Correct ZipCode");
    // now ziporpostalcode will contains the required value
   // Proceed with the value
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine("invalid zipCode");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested way.

Use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate your input to `int`.

```
var input =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    
if(int.TryParse(input, out ziporpostalcode )
{
    // you have int zipcode here
}
else
{
   // show error. 
}
```

Comment: Ahh... yes, Thanks @un-lucky. fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Zip Code");
        try
        {
            ziporpostalcode = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You Enter {0}", ziporpostalcode);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occured, Enter only Number");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: how to make it easy not using a if else condtion or exeption